# how to exactly install pip on windows, especially part dealing with command prompt?

Tags: python-2.7, pip, installation, windows-7

While installing pip on windows 7, its showing "access denied" when we command the command prompt to install pip by using `get-pip.py`
I am using command prompt as administrator...I have added the scripts path to environment variables...but nothing seems to be working out

Comment: Hey, may I know what full version of Python 2.7 are you using? By default pip should be there if Python >=2.7.9 or  >=3.4.

Nonetheless what is the permission of `get-pip.py` file when you downloaded? Error trace will also be helpful.

Comment: I am using python 2.7.1 and I was not asked for any permissions when i downloaded the file may be because I already had PyCharm and this pip file is also by PyCharm

Comment: Can you please attach the error trace when you run the command? Also do you have multiple version of python?

Can you share if this works: `python -m ensurepip --default-pip`

Comment: No I do not use multiple versions of python, I tried the code you asked me to, even for that it just writes "access is denied"  when I run the command, that's it, nothing else.

Comment: can you please put the complete error trace on question? Thanks.